# Eclipse: Define multiple working sets all at once

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to define 10 working sets in Eclipse and repeat it over a couple of workspaces.

- Is there a way to define the 10 working sets all at once? Rather than trudging thro the select working set drop down ten times?
- Is there a way to copy working set defs from one workspace to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 2nd problem, I found a duplication question here([Share / Export eclipse working sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369829/share-export-eclipse-working-sets)) which use AnyEdit  eclipse plugin.
 
For the 1st, I dont think there's any better choice.