# Unable to export Working Set in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I can't export my Working Set in Eclipse Juno.

How to reproduce:

- Start with a blank workspace.
- Create a Java project.
- Assign the project to a new Java Working Set.
- File -> Export -> Team -> Team Project Set.
- Check "Export working sets".
- Click "Select All".

Then I get the following error:
"None of the selected working sets have an available project to export."

What does it mean? Have I missed something? I thought that "Export Team Project Set" was the official way to share a Working Set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only export projects which have been added to a source control system (SVN, GIT, CVS...). Eclipse will try and check out the projects listed in the `psf` when it is imported.

There is no simple Export Working Set in Eclipse but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369829/share-export-eclipse-working-sets) answer for a plug-in that adds this.

Comment: Thanks, adding the project to a Git repository worked made it work! Why Eclipse requires this though is beyond me.

Comment: The intention is that you give the psf file to someone else and Eclipse will check out everything for them when they import the psf.

Answer (score 4):

No plugin is needed to. You should delete the provider element from the exported .psf file and you are done. The beginning of the file should look like the snippet and then should contain all your working sets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<workingSets editPageId="org.eclipse.ui.resourceWorkingSetPage" id="1393963554943_5" label="firstworkingset" name="firstworkingset">
```

If someone imports the projects and then this prepared Team Project Set, then only the sets will be set up but the projects aren't imported again. For a real example, check out the psf file in the [Xtext repo](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/devtools/org.eclipse.xtext.contributor/projectSet.psf).