# import an Eclipse "Working Set" in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Mars Milestone 4 (4.5.0M4)

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I would like to import an Eclipse "Working Set" in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, but I can't find this option anywhere

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default this option is not provided by eclipse. Use [AnyEdit Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) plugin to do this. Also refer this post [Share / Export eclipse working sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369829/share-export-eclipse-working-sets)